# How to debug, SQL Server exception, The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am loading a big file (~25 GB, 400 million lines) into the SQL Server 2014 using `SqlBulkCopy`.

My bulk copy size is 10k lines and timeout is 1 hour. The whole file is in a single transaction as I would like to store the entire file or roll back in case of failures. I have 3 indexes (one unique clustered index and other two are non clustered indexes) on this table.

Sometimes I get this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinuedOnSuccess(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)

In case of exception, I do a rollback of entire transaction but then I see one more exception while trying to rollback. I didn't understand why the `SqlTransaction` is not in usable state as my code doesn't close the connection/transaction anywhere else.

> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

I have debugged to some extent, in SSMS I see that there is a open transaction

```
select @@TRANCOUNT  ==> this gives "0" (I didn't understand why)

dbcc opentran ==> this gives me a open transaction

Oldest active transaction:
    SPID (server process ID): 58
    UID (user ID) : -1
    Name          : user_transaction
    LSN           : (159:2843368:1)
    Start time    : Dec 30 2014 11:20:13:903PM
    SID           : 0x0105000000000005150000005d28f57fd53ad8354354e02ae9881a00
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Then using this SQL script I figured out that it got stuck on the line

```
insert bulk dbo.#mytablename#
```

with status as running, timestamp exactly matching the time at which it threw the exception - 1 hour (bulk copy timeout). But I couldn't figure out why SQL Server got stuck here and why it is taking more time. Is there a way to debug this further?

```
SELECT 
   r.[session_id],
   c.[client_net_address],
   s.[host_name],
   c.[connect_time],
   [request_start_time] = s.[last_request_start_time],
   [current_time] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   r.[percent_complete],
   [estimated_finish_time] = DATEADD
       (
           MILLISECOND,
           r.[estimated_completion_time], 
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ),
   current_command = SUBSTRING
       (
           t.[text],
           r.[statement_start_offset]/2,
           COALESCE(NULLIF(r.[statement_end_offset], -1)/2, 2147483647)
       ),
   module = COALESCE(QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[objectid], t.[dbid])) 
       + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[objectid], t.[dbid])), '<ad hoc>'),
   [status] = UPPER(s.[status])
 FROM
     sys.dm_exec_connections AS c
 INNER JOIN
     sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
     ON c.session_id = s.session_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
     ON r.[session_id] = s.[session_id]
 OUTER APPLY
     sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.[sql_handle]) AS t
 WHERE
     c.session_id = 58;
```

Answer (score 1):

It timed out because **your bulk load will take over an hour to finish**. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), The timeout setting refers to

> Number of seconds for the operation to complete before it times out.

It makes sense that a 25GB file may take over an hour to load into the database, so why not try setting a higher timeout value so it has enough time to complete?

Comment: Consider performing the SqlBulkCopy in batches (e.g. WriteToServer of 50K records in a loop) so that each batch is in a separate transaction.

Comment: As per our requiremetns, we shouldn't have separate transaction per batch (WriteToServer 50k records)... AS of now we are calling WriteToServer for every 10k lines.. but the whole file will be in a single transaction

Comment: John M- The bulkcopytimeout (1 hr) is for writting only bulkcopybatchsize (10k lines) but not for whole file (25GB).